# General Form of a Open Set in the Product Topology in a Countably Infinite Product.

Tags: general-topology

Suppose $\{X_n\}_{n\in\Bbb N^+}$ is a family of topological spaces.  I understand that a typical basis element of the product topology has the form 
$$\prod_{n=1}^k U_n\times\prod_{n=k+1}^\infty X_n,$$
where $U_n$ is open in $X_n$ for $1\le n\le k$.

It seems to mean that an arbitrary open set in the product topology also has this form.

Let $X=\prod X_n$. Suppose $\{U_\alpha\}_{\alpha\in A}$ is a collection of open sets in $X$. Let 
$$U_\alpha=\prod_{n=1}^{k_\alpha}U_\alpha^n\times\prod_{n=k_\alpha+1}X_n.$$

Suppose, $k=\min\{k_\alpha:\alpha\in A\}$, which exists by the well-ordering of $\Bbb N^+$.  I'm getting

$$\bigcup_{\alpha\in A}U_\alpha=\prod_{n=1}^k\bigcup_\alpha U_\alpha^n\times\prod_{n=k+1}^\infty X_n.$$

Is this correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nope.

1. $A_1 \times B_1 \cup A_2 \times B_2 \neq ( A_1 \cup A_2 ) \times ( B_1 \cup B_2 )$ - a sum of two rectangles usually isn't a rectangle. For longer products/unions it doesn't work either.
2. For this to be correct, you would have to take $k = \max \{ k_{\alpha} : \alpha \in A \}.$ But what if it is infinite?

Comment: Ah yes.  I see what you're saying.

Comment: I should have checked 1. first, before going ahead.